# Session user_id shorten

Tags: php, session, header, account

i have the following variable / session:

```
$id = $Account->session('user_id');
```

now i want to make it shorter like:

```
$_SESSION['user_id']
```

but that's not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: did u start session?????????

Comment: I need it like this: $_SESSION['user_id']
Because i need that format in a script i bought.

But my format is: $Account->session('user_id');

Answer (score 0):

For storing value to session you need to start session. Try it something like below

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // store session data
  $_SESSION['user_id']=$var;
?>
```